# UnavailableError: Firebase database instance is inactive

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have a project in which we run several computations and then publish a summary of the results to a Firebase Realtime Database.

For publishing to Firebase, I implemented the python class as follows:

```
"""Package for all Firebase related tasks"""
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import db
from firebase_admin.exceptions import InvalidArgumentError

from ngtlib.auth import auth_config, project

class FirebaseConnection:
    def __init__(self, app_name=None):
        """Initiate a Firebase Connection"""
        self.cred = None
        self.app = None
        self.options = None
        self.app_name = app_name
        self.environment = project.get_environment()  # custom business logic variable
        self.init_client()

    def init_client(self):
        """Init the Firebase Authentication
        """
        # Initiate a Firebase Connection
        self.cred = firebase_admin.credentials.ApplicationDefault()
        self.options = auth_config.firebase_config_json()
        self.app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(self.cred, self.options, name=self.app_name)

        # We do this after since initialize_app does not handle if options is empty dict just if is None
        # see firebase_admin._AppOptions
        if self.options is None:
            self.options = dict()

    def update(self, node, values):
        """(Safely) update a single node
        """
        data = dict()
        data[node] = values
        ref = db.reference(self.environment, url=self.options.get("databaseURL"), app=self.app)
        ref.update(data)

    def get(self, node, shallow=False):
        """Read from a certain node
        """
        ref = db.reference(self.environment, url=self.options.get("databaseURL"), app=self.app).child(node)
        return ref.get(shallow=shallow)
```

I noticed that during certain times of the day, when publishing results to Firebase, I receive the following error, from time to time (now always):

```
firebase_admin.exceptions.UnavailableError: Firebase database instance is inactive
at request (/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py:932)
at update (/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/firebase_admin/db.py:342)
```

What exactly is this error and where does it come from?

Comment: What are your current database security rules? You might have had your database shut down because you left them too public (check your emails).

Comment: Not applicable. Database is quite restricted.